# Any clue on how to fix StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation?

Tags: flutter, google-play

I ran some sample automated testing in a sample app and got the warining below. But teh text does not really say anything.

Has anyone come accress similar warnings? I seems internal working of flutter.

> StrictMode policy violation:
>   android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation:
>   Landroid/util/LongArray;->get(I)J
>
> Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;->getSourceNodeId()J
>     at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:407)
>
> Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;->getSourceNodeId()J
>     at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
>
> :
>   Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;->mChildNodeIds:Landroid/util/LongArray;
>     at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:407)
>
> Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;->mChildNodeIds:Landroid/util/LongArray;
>     at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
>
> Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityRecord;->getSourceNodeId()J
>     at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:407)
>
> Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityRecord;->getSourceNodeId()J
>     at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)

Comment: Same as you. Found anything ?

Comment: have you got the answer? I have been facing this issue

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I don't know what it is or how to solve it.

Answer (score 15):

I known the question is quite old, but answering anyway
There is a closed issue on the flutter github that seems to correspond to your stack trace : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36915#issuecomment-525668810
The pined comment explain what happen : Call to SDK API using ReflectionAccessors Class which is discouraged by google as mentionned in https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces
As explained in the github thread, it is safe to ignore those warning because the reflexion calls are protected and fail silently.
Hopes this helps